# Performance considerations for calculating vectors in C#

Tags: c#

My goal is to improve the speed/performance of vector calculation using operator overloading.

Say I have the following method:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds two vectors together and returns the result.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vLeft">The left vector.</param>
        /// <param name="vRight">The right vector.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the vector result.</returns>
        public static Vector2D operator +(Vector2D vLeft, Vector2D vRight)
        {
            Vector2D vResult = new Vector2D();

            vResult.m_x = vLeft.m_x + vRight.m_x;
            vResult.m_y = vLeft.m_y + vRight.m_y;

            return vResult;
        }
```

This instantiates a new object of type Vector2D, does some arithmetic, and then returns the result. It seems like a lot of stuff going on, but to increase the speed, I made Vector2D a struct instead of a class for direct manipulation since it's a value type and not a reference.

I'm wondering primarily if this style has better performance gain with returning the result:

```
        public static Vector2D operator +(Vector2D vLeft, Vector2D vRight)
        {  
            return new Vector2D(vLeft.m_x + vRight.m_x, vLeft.m_y + vRight.m_y);
        }
```

While structs at value types, this brings about another problem. The vector being returned is a binary copy; however, this is common in C++ programs I have worked with in the past.

At any rate, I would like to hear if there's a way to improve the speed of vector manipulation using operator overloading.

Comment: Consider ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Having said this you should care for your *actual* problems, not for some minor method of which you think they might be faster for let´s say 1% - which would be much. Don´t make your classes value-types for the sake of optimization. Have in mind the actual *semantics* that value-types bring with, which is they represent a single *value*.

Comment: When performance is that critical don´t use a managed language. Of course it´s allways needed that your software doesn´t run too slow for *any kind of system*. However in many cases the difference between a struct and a class can be ignored as it effects the overwall performance less than you think. When you really have some problems regarding performance use a profiler that will enlighten the *actual* bottlenecks.

Comment: Sorry, Beere, this is ignorant. First, there are real brutal differences between classes and struct, Second there may be overaching reasons to go for performance early. Third, if you know what you do and do it right, the idifference may not justify using unmanaged code. Lots of assumptions in your comment instead of answering the question.

Comment: @TomTom That´s why it´s a comment. Apart from this I already suggested to use a profiler that will enlighten if this is the actual problem. Btw.: of course there are differences between the two concepts, in particular regarding performance. However this difference is quite often overestimated and in particular due to the value-type-logic even negated. Last but not least the link also sais: "there´s 3% of critical  mass where we *have* to worry about such things".

Comment: Yes, but then this is a Q&A site and someone asking a specific question can be assumed to be in the right context.

Comment: @TomTom We don´t know but from my experience users here are not allways aware of their context, in particular when it comes to performance.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)?

Answer (score 1):

You might be barking up the wrong tree.  If you use the system vector structs (not classes) and a alfway decent modern runtime, then the runtime will optimze that and use SIMD instructions - you can not bat that. http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/simd-enabled-vector-types-with-c/240168888 The use of non-standard vecrots already puts you significantly into "slow as molass" territory and there is no way around it.

SIMD support was added in the RyuJit runtime and it is times faster than what you normally get from bytecode.

Comment: @Phil It is one of the areas that .NET IICRC 4.5 did very big improovements (some others are - ah - "meh" style bad). If you can push things into the SIMD structs, you will be way faster than what you can write in C# - no way around it.

Comment: No, counterproductive. The Vector2 operations are determined by what can be pushe to hardware, iirc. I would suggest opening tickets at the github project for .NET to see about what is missing. Inheritance will block the use of SIMD -> not good. No decent solution here, sorry, the language does not allow it.

Comment: Is this generally fine? Use my regular Vector2D class (my own wrapper), but replace the old "float x, y" to Vector2 (SIMD), so it would be Vector2 m_pos, and then operate with m_pos.X and m_pos.Y in my member methods. Would that cause any problems?

Comment: I am not sure. You definitely make it hard for the JIT to be efficient by this. I would avoid it - or at least do some heavy testing to make sure I do not loose efficiency due to JIT issues.